# What does Apple normally announce at events?

Tags: macos, apple-inc

Tomorrow (October 20th, 2010) Apple will announce something.

What have they announced at previous Mac events and what are some of the things are "usual"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an open ended question;

Traditionally Apple at events such as MacWorld, WWDC, etc. run down as follows:

- Run down of current company progress showcasing how much Mac OS X has grown
- New hardware updates with technical details and great product shots.
- New software - whether it's upgrades or completely brand new products. Lots of demos.
- Occasionally a one more thing, usually the biggest thing of the show **if** it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of events, Apple announces new/updated software/hardware/service products.

Usually, invitation card hints what is behind the curtain.